# Ncurses over ssh - will they be displayed?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, ncurses

I'd like to create a small terminal utility requiring a bit of *very simple* graphics. Therefore I'd like to use ncurses.

Now what I'm wondering is: will a ncurses program or python script that uses ncurses be visible over ssh? I'd also like the colors to be visible as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works (no surprise), but if you are running a command via ssh (rather than the default shell), you will have to use the `-t` option to allocate a terminal.

The [ssh manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1) says

> **`-t`**
>   Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute
>   arbitrary screen-based programs on  a remote machine, which can be
>   very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.   Multiple **`-t`**
>   options force tty allocation, even  if ssh has no local tty.